# Uploading csv to windows azure storage with php

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

Trying to upload a csv from a remote URL to azure storage using the PHP SDK. I seem to keep getting this error. I have tried it without the SDK using curl and i still get the same error.

```
`PUT resulted in a `403 Server failed to authenticate the request. 
Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.` response: ﻿
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate (truncated...) 
in C:\wamp64\www\azurescript\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113
```

Here is my PHP code which i am using:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;
use MicrosoftAzure\Blob\Models\SetBlobPropertiesOptions;


$key = base64_encode("abc");

$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=username;AccountKey={$key}";

$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

// Grab the csv from the remote url
$csv = fopen("http://www.xxxxx.com/wp-cron.phpexport_hash=yyyyyy&export_id=1&action=get_data", "r");
$blobName = "test";

try    {
    // Upload the blob
    $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("container", $blobName, $csv);
}
catch(ServiceException $e){

    // Errors
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Cant seem to this. Some guidance would be nice

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to 403 auth failed. Please maker sure:

1. Your account name and account key is valid and not expired. You can confirm this by trying loging with Azure Storage Explorer, or check on your Azure Portal.
2. You do not need base64_encode($key) again after receiving your key from Azure Storage. The key received from Azure Storage is already base64_encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The auth issue is related to your key not being properly set up. Not sure why you decided to encode it, but... you need to use the storage access key exactly as it's presented to you.

In fact, the entire connection string is constructed for you already; no need to build it yourself.